# Creating sympy matrix using function

Tags: python, matrix, constructor, sympy, callable

The sympy documentation has this example for creating a matrix using a rule:

```
>>> def f(i,j):
        if i == j:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
>>> Matrix(4, 4, f)
[1  0  0  0]
[          ]
[0  1  0  0]
[          ]
[0  0  1  0]
[          ]
[0  0  0  1]
```

How would I go about using a rule with arguments? For example, using the function:

```
>>> def f(i,j,l=1):
        if i == j:
            return 1*l
        else:
            return 0
```

I don't know how to call such a function.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm not looking for a solution that solves this particular example - I'm looking for a more general solution. Please assume that the function which is the rule for the creation of the matrix - that is, `f` in the example - is arbitrarily complex. That is, it can't simply/easily be replicated with a lambda function. So in other words, the arguments (`l` in the example) must be included in the call to the function (`f`). Is it possible to do this?

EDIT 2: Basically I want to be able to specify `f` as independent function (by that I mean not a lambda function) and then call it as part of the `Matrix` construction with any additional arguments (additional to the first 2 compulsory arguments). I've tried calling the example function with code like:

```
>>> Matrix(4,4,f,l=7)
```

With the expectation that it will return:

```
[7  0  0  0]
[          ]
[0  7  0  0]
[          ]
[0  0  7  0]
[          ]
[0  0  0  7]
```

But this does not work.

```
>>> Matrix(4,4,f,{l=7})
```

Doesn't work either. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `lambda` expression like this:

```
l = 5
Matrix(4, 4, lambda i,j: l if i==j else 0)
```

or directly

```
Matrix(4, 4, lambda i,j: 5 if i==j else 0)
```

which would then give you:

```
Matrix([
[5, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 5, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 5, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 5]])
```

You can of course also use more complicated expressions like

```
Matrix(4, 4, lambda i,j: i*j if i==j else i-j)
```

which would give you

```
Matrix([
[0, -1, -2, -3],
[1,  1, -1, -2],
[2,  1,  4, -1],
[3,  2,  1,  9]])
```

Comment: @Charlie: Could you then also add a more complex `f` i.e. an example for what you actually try to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want this so that you can generate a different matrix depending on the value of the argument. In that case, you should create a separate outer function to return the Matrix, like

```
def diagonal(l):
    def f(i, j):
        if i == j:
            return l
        else: 
            return 0
    return Matrix(4, 4, f)
```

(and by the way, for this specific example, you can just use `diag(*[l]*4)` or `eye(4)*l`).

You could also make it so that your function gets called as `Matrix(4, 4, f(l))`.

```
def f(l):
    def _inner(i, j):
        if i == j:
            return l
        else:
            return 0
    return _inner
```

In other words, `f(l)` generates a function that gives the values of the matrix for that `l`.

There's no way to modify the `Matrix` constructor itself so that you would write `Matrix(4, 4, f, l)`. But either of the above should be workable (write a function that generates matrices, or write a function that generates functions).

Comment: Do you know of a way to do what I ask if ``f`` has the same structure as in the question (i.e. with ``l`` as an argument)? If you can, I'd accept that because I think that would be a more 'pythonic' answer.

Comment: @Charlie I really don't understand what you are looking for. How do you envision the argument `l` being passed in?  Is the problem that you already have a function `f` that is three arguments? If that's the case, you can use `functools.partial` to convert it to a two argument version.

Comment: It may be the case that what I want to do is impossible, though I'm not sure. It seems like you're on the right track for the best alternative with ``functools.partial``. For future readers, could you please edit your answer to demonstrate ``functools.partial``?

Comment: But I still really don't understand what you're looking for. Can you at least specify how you would like it to work?

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question again. Please see edit 2.

Comment: I guess if you really want you could also write your own `matrix()` function which translates `matrix(4, 4, f, l)` into the `Matrix` you want.